# How to activate a new execution line and a new file in VS Code debugger development

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I am developing a debugger with Visual Studio Code.
The problem I have is moving between the files, changing the current line and file being debugged.

Suppose the current debugger execution line is line 10 in file1.
On a "step into" request, I can move to a file2 and set the execution line to 20.
But when I do "step into" second time, and now want to activate the execution line 30 in file3, VS Code doesn't do it - I keep staying on the same execution line 20 in file2 (file3 is not opened at all by VS Code).

I am using same way of activating files/exec lines as in the mock debugger.
E.g. I use fireEventsForLine(), namely this.sendEvent('stopOnStep'); call in the debugger runtime.

Any sample code of activating a random execution line in a random file will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
In order to move the current execution line from FileX, LineX to FileY LineY, you should make sure that your stack trace is correct. This is the most important navigation item in debugging, the stack trace. The top element must be FileY, LineY.

Hope it helps anyone, I did miss out this part.